# MVC CORE setting a session

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

I've been following the Microsoft documentation trying to set a session using this line

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString(SessionKeyName, "Rick");
```

from the page
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?tabs=aspnetcore2x

but it gives the error

`'ISession' does not contain a definition for 'SetString'`

There's a `Set` option, but that takes a byte.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong and why I'm using the wrong `HttpContext.Session`?

Comment: Obviously you forgot the using: `using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetString`,`GetString`,`GetInt32` and `SetInt32` are [extension methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) on `ISession` defined inside the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespace. So to use these, you should add a using statement to this namespace in your class.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
```

Now in your class, you can use these extension methods

```
HttpContext.Session.SetString("Test", "Rick");
HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("Age", 25);
```